# How to sum and copy paste in sheet 2 row incrementally?

Tags: excel, vba

My requirement is to sum data in the range of sheet1 (A2:A9) and copy the output of sum to sheet2 ("A1").

I plan to schedule the code to run for every 5 minutes. For the first 5 minute run the output has to be stored in sheet2("A1"). For the 10th minute run output to be stored in sheet2("A2"). For the 15th minute run output has to stored in sheet2("A3").

```vb
Sub Hello()
Dim myData As DataObject
Set myData = New DataObject
Dim a As String
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A9").Select
a = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection)
myData.SetText a
myData.PutInClipboard
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Select
myData.GetFromClipboard
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
Call Schedule
End Sub

Sub Schedule()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "Hello"
End Sub
```

Like this the output has to be stored incrementally.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code below would run every 5 minutes for 1 hour; to have it run for, e.g 2 hours instead, you would have to increase the upper limit of the `i` value in *Schedule()* (from 60) to 120 etc.

```
Public runCount As Long
Sub Hello()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        runCount = runCount + 1
        .Cells(runCount, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A9"))
        .Cells(runCount, 2).Value = (runCount * 5) & "th minute"
    End With
End Sub
Sub Schedule()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 5 To 60 step 5
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(INT(i/60)&":"&(i Mod 60)), "Hello"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @SpectralInstance, Thank u so much for the answer, I have executed the code you provide, but instead of running every 5 minutes it is running multiple time within a minute.  Below is the code I executed with few modification and also attached the result.

Comment: Public runCount As Long
    Public Interval As Date
    Sub Schedule()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 5 To 60 Step 5
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(Int(i / 60) & ":" & (i Mod 60)), "hello"
    Next i
    End Sub

Comment: With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        runCount = runCount + 1
        .Cells(runCount, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A9"))
        .Cells(runCount, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B9"))
        .Cells(runCount, 1).Value = (Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss"))
        .Cells(runCount, 4).Value = .Cells(runCount, 3) / .Cells(runCount, 2)
    End With
    Call Schedule
    End Sub

Comment: ```
15:16:20 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:17:11 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:18:00 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:18:33 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:18:54 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:21:00 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:21:20 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:21:33 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:22:11 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:23:00 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:23:33 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:23:54 13160 44276 3.36443769
15:24:00 13160 44276 3.36443769
```
Above is the result. I have execute the code by selecting sub hello() manually in the code section. Please correct me if am doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: Code spread over several comments is **very** difficult to read... The code I posted executes every 5 minutes for me; the suggestion that comes to mind is to change the `Application.OnTime` line to the following: `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(Int(i / 60) & ":" & (i Mod 60) & ":00"), "Hello"`